# Pdf not showing chinese characters(ITextRenderer/FlyingSaucer)

Tags: html, css, spring, pdf, thymeleaf

i am facing some issues with displaying the field with chinese/tamil/arabic characters in it. Lets say the field is "S额Y", only "SY" is displayed.

For the majority of this project, I am using Avenir fonts, which I understand does not support chinese characters. Hence I downloaded Notosans fonts from google to use for those foreign characters specifically.

1. Download Notosans fonts from google
2. Added into my fonts folder in my project(the path is correct)
3. Instead of using renderer.getFontResolver().addFonts(), I added the configuration into the css instead, which works for the other fonts.

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: Noto sans;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-style: normal;
     src: url('../../fonts/NotoSans.ttf');
     -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
     -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

.name{
  padding: 4px 16px 4px 16px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<td class="name"th:text="${name}"></td>
```

4. I even tried the Noto Sans SC which is for simplified chinese, and it does not work.

This only happens in pdf, I tried generating in html and it displays without any issues.

I tried the api method, and it does not work.

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link th:href="@{https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@300&family=Noto+Sans:wght@300&display=swap}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The following is the dependencies I used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Will absolutely thankful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Problem is even after changing the library i used, openhtmltopdf, the problem stays.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, so for some reason font-face is not recognizing opentype. Simplified chinese and Traditional chinese are in .otf, while Tamil is in .ttf, the tamil one work.  Technically i did not solve it, but i manage to display it after finding a different font that is in .ttf.